# bootstrap col-auto layout height alignment breaking when removing a button component

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am trying to get a flex column layout using bootstrap with the header and footer area taking auto height and the content area scrollable. When we insert components inside the footer and header column it will take the size of the components and the rest of the space will be taken by the content area. So far it's working very well. But when I hide/remove the `previous button`, the footer with `col-auto` class the height alignment breaks. Please help.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector('.prev-btn').remove();
}, 2000);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid p-0 h-100">
  <div class="row g-0 flex-column h-100">
    <header class="col-auto bg-secondary">
      <nav class="navbar bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand">Navbar</a>
          <form class="d-flex" role="search">
            <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="col d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center overflow-auto">
      <div class="col-6 py-3 m-auto">
        Content area
      </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="col-auto">
      <div class="container-fluid p-3 bg-light">
        <div class="row g-0 align-items-center">
          <div class="col">
            <button class="btn fw-bold btn-outline-danger shadow-none">CANCEL &amp; RESTART</button>
          </div>
          
          <div class="col-auto px-3 text-center">STEP 1 OF 4</div>
          
          <div class="col">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
              <button class="btn fw-bold btn-outline-secondary px-5 me-3 shadow-none prev-btn">PREVIOUS</button>
              <button class="btn fw-bold btn-outline-primary px-5 shadow-none">NEXT</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be happening because the CANCEL & RESTART button is wrapping during reflow. You can use Bootstrap's `text-nowrap` class to prevent this, though that may require other layout changes on smaller screens. One solution might be to move the "1 of 4" label above the buttons for mobile.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector('.prev-btn').remove();
}, 2000);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid p-0 h-100">
  <div class="row g-0 flex-column h-100">
    <header class="col-auto bg-secondary">
      <nav class="navbar bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand">Navbar</a>
          <form class="d-flex" role="search">
            <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="col d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center overflow-auto">
      <div class="col-6 py-3 m-auto">
        Content area
      </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="col-auto">
      <div class="container-fluid p-3 bg-light">
        <div class="row g-0 align-items-center">
          <div class="col">
            <button class="btn fw-bold btn-outline-danger shadow-none text-nowrap">CANCEL &amp; RESTART</button>
          </div>
          
          <div class="col-auto px-3 text-center">STEP 1 OF 4</div>
          
          <div class="col">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
              <button class="btn fw-bold btn-outline-secondary px-5 me-3 shadow-none prev-btn">PREVIOUS</button>
              <button class="btn fw-bold btn-outline-primary px-5 shadow-none">NEXT</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```